# Magento 2, Add custom attribute after description field

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I need to add a new custom attribute after description field.

How make it?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I want to show the attributes how this image:

[image]

Comment: admin side ????

Comment: Hi, I want to show some information in frontend side

Comment: please atatach screen shot

Comment: @RK Rathor look the image in the post

Comment: add new tab ???

Comment: Inside the tab "details"

Comment: Follow this you can get the required result:
1-https://www.customerparadigm.com/adding-a-new-tab-to-the-product-details/
2-https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/

Comment: Hi Hafiz, in this mode I can create a new tab with attribute... But how can I add the attributes after description, in same tab details?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add attribute from admin side follow these steps :

**Create a new attribute :**

```
--> go to stores -> attributes -> product (http://prntscr.com/nf5a9w)
--> create a new attrbiute (http://prntscr.com/nf5aoa)
--> visible on catelog page must be yes (http://prntscr.com/nf5fn1)
```

**Keep it in attribute set :**

```
--> go to stores -> attributes -> Attribute set  (http://prntscr.com/nf58xz)
--> select your attribute set or default (http://prntscr.com/nf594u)
--> drag and drop your attribute to any group (http://prntscr.com/nf59ur)
```